# C++ Try Catch Throw

Tags: c++, exception, linked-list, stack

I'm trying to throw an error in my stack program whenever I try to add numbers together when the stack is empty.  Inside my top function of my stack class I throw an exception in case I don't have anything on the stack.  I then proceed to create a try and catch block in my main program to catch the error and display a message.  However, I get the error listed below and I don't know how to fix it.

Error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'char const*'
```

Class Top():

```
 const T& top() const throw (std::string){
                    if(m_next != NULL){
                            return m_data;
                    }
                    else{
                            throw("Nothing on the Stack");
                    }
            };
```

int main():

```
int main(){
    string op;
    RobotCalc<int>* stack = new RobotCalc<int>;
    int operand1;
    int operand2;


    cin >> op;
    while(op != "@"){
            if(op == "+"){
                    try{
                    operand1 = stack->top();
                    stack->pop();
                    operand2 = stack->top();
                    stack->pop();
                    stack->push(operand1 + operand2);
                    }
                    catch (string e){
                            cout << e;
                    }
            }
```

There is more to the code, but this is where the problem lies.  The class function has 2 member variables: m_data of type T (int in this case) and a pointer to the next RobotClass (member of the stack).  This is a linkedlist version of a stack.

Answer (score 2):

You are catching message of type `string`, while throw is throwing `const char*`. Catch `const char*` or just put a ".

Answer (score 1):

`throw/catch` doesn't do conversion on the object thrown. If you throw a `const char*` then you need to catch `const char*`, not `std::string`.

The error message is telling you that there was an uncaught exception.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Steve. However, you should catch exceptions followed by the error message instead of a string. For example:

```
  catch (exceptionName e) {
     //catch block
  }
```

[c++ standard exceptions](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/exception/exception/)